# Javascript Functions, Ready, Click, Each, Next, This, and Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just started learning web development and someone gave me this code to use. However, I want to understand it so that I can change it the way that I would like. However, I am having some trouble understanding it completely. I have the basics of computer programming. I just am having a hard time understanding what this code here is doing. I've done some research here https://api.jquery.com/. I understand the individual concepts kind of, but can't put them together. So here is what I understand so far:

`.ready()`: It makes sure that the page is loaded and is ready for use. And I'm assuming the following code won't execute unless the page is fully loaded and ready for interaction.

`.click()`: Basically responds to a click.

`.each()`: Kind of a like a for loop.

`.next()`: Goes to the next element.

`.hide()`: Hides the element (which is kind of confusing, because it doesn't actually hide it, it just makes it jump up)?

`.toggle()`: It reveals a hidden element?

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.info').click(function(){
        $('.info').each(function(){
            $(this).next().hide();
        });
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
});
```

I think that's it. But I'm not sure how it all fits in. Could someone please explain it to me?

Also, why doesn't the code above work without this line:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: The code above does not work without this line because the code you use is jQuery.
The code does following:
document.ready says that everything is loaded fine and javascript can start executing.
info.click says -> ok there was a click event. 
Now it iterates through every class .info and hides the next() info (.hide()).
toggle basically says -> if its hidden show it and if its shown hide it.

Comment: ".ready() - It makes sure that the page is loaded" - not exactly, DOM is ready, but page content doesn't have to be loaded completelly...

Comment: These are not javascript functions, they are jqueery cruft

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

loads the jQuery library from the CDN URL above. This Javascript file contains the definition of all the above functions you're using as well as many other useful functions. You can read more on the official docs. https://api.jquery.com/

**Code Explanation**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

This registers a `ready` event on `document`. In other words, the callback anonymous function is called when the `DOM` is completely loaded and is *ready* to be manipulated.

```
    $('.info').click(function () {
```

Just like the `ready` event handler, this code binds a `click` event on all the elements having class of `info`.

```
        $('.info').each(function () {
            $(this).next().hide();
        });
```

This part of code will loop over all the elements having the class of `info` and hides the next element of each element one by one.'

```
        $(this).next().toggle();
```

This will toggle the visibility of the next element of the clicked-`$(this)` element. Not really, this is showing the next element as in the above `each` loop, you've hide all the next elements of `.info` class.

```
    }); // End of click
}); // End of ready
```

---

Your code can also written without loop as

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.info').click(function () {

        $('.info').not(this).next().hide();
        // Hide all elements that are nextSibling of the elements having class info other than the clicked one

        $(this).next().show();
        // Show the next element of the clicked element
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should know js is a language, and most of the functions you mentioned here are jQuery functions.

jQuery is a library written in js which has a lot of functions and options to support development.

So the line of script you included, loads the jQuery library in to the page.

As for the other questions:

> `.ready()`: It makes sure that the page is loaded and is ready for use. And I'm assuming the following code won't execute unless the page is fully loaded and ready for interaction.

As you wrote - this is a function to deal with page loading, although the following code **will** execute before page is done loading, and that is because js is a non-blocking script

so the proper use of `.ready()` is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ....//all code you need after page is fully ready goes here
});
```

> .click(): Basically responds to a click.

Correct. this responds to a [DOM event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) of a [DOM element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction). It is really impotent to understand what is DOM and how to use it when developing for web.

```
$(element).click(function(){
    ....//all code you need after clicking element goes here
});
```

> .each(): Kind of a like a for loop.

Correct. this loops through DOM elements, and in each iteration you get a reference to the current one

```
$(elements).each(function(){
    var element = $(this) //jquery wrapper of current iterated DOM element. this refers to current iterated DOM element
});
```

> .next(): Goes to the next element.

this is a way of "walking" through the DOM tree, to manipulate elements in it

> .hide(): Hides the element (which is kind of confusing, because it doesn't actually hide it, it just makes it jump up)?

this does actually hide the element. This would probably be done using css to hide the element

> .toggle(): It reveals a hidden element?

this is a shortcut for `hide()` and `show()`. It checks if element is hidden, and if it is, it uses `show()`, otherwise, it uses `hide()`. as mentioned, this would also probably be done with css